# How two find two most distant points with only distance metric (instead of coordinate)?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I meet a question that given a set of data points, I need to find two points that are most distant. In my setting, there is no coordinate for each point, only I can do is calculate the distance between two points with a specific distance metric (which satisfies all three axioms, identity of indiscernibles, symmetry, and triangle inequality).

I know if these points are in the plane, i.e. they have coordinates, then there are algorithms that are better than O(n^2) to find the two most distant points, for example this question [How to find two most distant points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736290/how-to-find-two-most-distant-points). But is there any algorithm better than O(n^2) that can solve my question?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems relatively clear that if the algorithm runs is shorter time than n², then it doesn't have time to examine all the pairwise distances. In that case, how can it be sure that one of the non-looked-at distances isn't much higher than the others?

Comment: Long story short: it might be possible to do better than n² if you have additional assumptions on your distances (for instance, do they satisfy the [triangular inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Metric_space)?). But without any extra assumptions, you can't hope to do better than computing all the pairwise distances and keeping the maximum.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes here by saying "distance metric" I mean the distance that satisfies all three axioms (identity of indiscernible, symmetry, triangle inequality), under these conditions, can we have some better algorithm?

Comment: I think that the answer to this question is: "No".  I am not an expert in this, but those "*Less than O(n^2)*" for Euclidian geometry actually exploit low dimensionality and are something like `O(N^[d/2])` where `d` is the number of dimensions.  So even if you had coordinates, but they were in say, 10 dimensions, you couldn't use that approach to get less than O(n^2), it would be at least `O(n^5)`.  So effectively, above 4 dimensions, you'd just use the brute-force "*compare all pairs*" method anyway.  So without more knowledge of your distance metric, its `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider the metric induced by a complete graph minus one edge.

Answer (score 0):

**A counter-example:**

In the Euclidean metric, A-B are the farthest. In Manhattan, B-C.

[image]